# libraries for building HTML form using PHP

Tags: php, html, templates

I'm looking for building HTML form using PHP but I was wondering that may be libraries already exist. do you know any open source library I can use ?

Do you think, it's a good idea to create function to construct HTML form using php ? is there any risk on performance (loading the pages of my website) ?

```
function input($label,$id,$type)
{
    echo $label.' <input type="'.$type.'" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" />';
}

input('User name','login','text');
```

My purpose is to build a library to maitain quickly code.

Comment: There is no harm in doing that. There are however FormBuilder classes out there. So why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Daan it will be a good idea, can you give me an example of formBuilder classes I can use for my project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of functions I created back in the days. I use them for projects, that are not framework dependent. Nowadays I prefer using Symfony's Form component when possible.

Take a look, it will give you an idea.

```
function lb($text, $forid='', $style='', $attr='') 
{
    if($style!='')
        $style='style="'.$style.'"';

    if($forid!='')
        $forid='for="'.$forid.'"';

    return '<label '.$style.$forid.' '.$attr.'>'.$text.'</label>';
}

//generates input field, and populates inputs. Good for edit forms too.
function in($name, $cust_val='', $style='', $attr='', $set_id=true)
{
    global $edit;
    $val='';
    if(isset($edit[$name]))
        $val=$edit[$name];
    if($cust_val!='')
    {
        $val=$cust_val;
    }

    if($style!='')
        $style='style="'.$style.'"';

    $setid='';
    if($set_id)
        $setid="id=\"".$name."\"";

    return '<input type="text" name="'.$name.'" '.$setid.' '.$attr.' '.$style.' value="'.ht($val).'">';
}

/*
 * Prints multiple <td></td> for a table structure
 * 
 * @param array vals - values to be used inside tds
 * @param boolean encloseInTR when true puts <tr> outside tds
 */
function tds($vals, $encloseInTR=false)
{
    $out='';
    foreach($vals as $v)
    {
        $out.='<td>'.$v.'</td>';
    }

    if($encloseInTR)
        $out = '<tr>'.$out.'</tr>';

    return $out;
}


/*
 * Prints multiple <th></th> for a table structure
 * 
 * @param array vals - values to be used inside ths
 * @param boolean $encloseInTHEAD when true puts <thead> outside th
 * @param class class var to be added to th
 */
function ths($vals, $encloseInTHEAD=false, $class='')
{
    $out='';
    foreach($vals as $v)
    {
        if($class!='')
            $out.='<th class="'.$class.'">'.$v.'</th>';
        else
            $out.='<th>'.$v.'</th>';
    }

    if($encloseInTHEAD)
        $out = '<thead>'.$out.'</thead>';

    return $out;
}

//alias htmlspecialchars
function ht($string)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

And this is how my form code would look like:

```
$form =
 form_start(..)
.lb('First name','')
.in('name','','width:400px;')

.lb('Telefon','').cl() 
.in('tel','','width:400px;')
//...
.form_end()
;
```

Answer (score 1):

No risks in performance as what you are doing is basically what all the FormBuilder classes in PHP frameworks do already.
Only thing I'd suggest is to HTML-sanitize your input, specifically:

```
function input($label,$id,$type)
{
   echo htmlspecialchars($label).' <input type="'.htmlspecialchars($type, ENT_QUOTES).'" id="'.htmlspecialchars($id, ENT_QUOTES).'" name="'.htmlspecialchars($id, ENT_QUOTES).'" />';
}

input('User name','login','text');
```

This to avoid possible XSS attacks, code injections, and view problems.